# Wikipedia search API call using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, jsonp, wikipedia-api

I need to implement search function using Wikipedia API. So when user types a key, I need to make a call to the Wikipedia API and show the matching results. I don't need to use any other libraries like jQuery. I have to write the code using JavaScript. I have tried lot but failed.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a cross-domain [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) request .

**Example request:**

```
var jsonp_handler = function(data)
{
    // Do something with received data
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&callback=jsonp_handler&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500&titles=bill';

document.head.appendChild(script);
// or document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); in older browsers;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7adoxbz/1/)

You can [explore](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=San_Francisco&prop=images&imlimit=20&format=jsonfm) the [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tutorial) to get yourself familiar with the response objects .

Comment: refused to execute script from 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsoncallback=jsonp_handler&titles=chuck' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Comment: So how to acces received data from api?

Comment: the received data stored in `data` argument of the `jsonp_handler` function .